# Group Images in android based on Date Taken

Tags: java, android, image, android-gridview

How can I group images based on Date Taken in android ?

Using following code snippet, I can get the image lists sorted in time :

```
    String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC";
    imagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null,null, orderBy);
    int image_column_index = imagecursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
```

I need to show these images in groups . Like :

1/3/2015 20 photos

//20 photos will be shown in group

1/4/2015 13 photos

//13 photos will be shown in group